# Spring System Property Resolved Too Early

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I am using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in Spring 3.2.14.RELEASE in a web application. I have the below segment in my PropertyContext.xml file.

```
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="properties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:globalDefinitions.properties</value>
            <value>file:${user.home}/myapplication.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

When I run

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests=true
```

I open the generated war file and see that **locations** value for the second line is already resolved to *${user.home}* of my laptop. 
I am expecting it to happen when Spring Context is created.

We are building the war file on a build server and then transferring it to Test/Prod machines so it gives us troubles when we have different ${user.home} values.

What am I doing wrong?Is it expected behaviour or do I have some other maven plugings interfering(that I need to check)?

Comment: It *could be* that the maven resources plugin is pre-processing the file when you launch the `mvn` command. Try to [configure it](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html) to exclude your specific file/directory.

Comment: Do you mean after mvn install, the ***.properties file has been filled with your laptop home address? Or you directly let maven set the ${user.home} in your context XML? Anyway, I think you should try https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Comment: It's almost certainly Maven resource filtering.

Comment: @BackSlash indeed thank you very much. You can write it up as an answer if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is Maven resource plugin processing the files under src/main/recources and evaluating the ${user.home} value in the build phase.(Thanks @BackSlash)

So I have disabled filtering for PropertyContext in maven resource plugin and it started behaving as expected.